# Request.Url on Azure with custom domain

Tags: nancy

When requesting a page from an azure website with custom domain hosting Nancy solution, http://test.mydomain.com/page/bla for example, NancyFX for `Request.Url` returns http://test.azurewebsites.net:80/page/bla

Is it possible to return Url with custom domain request was made to?

Comment: You probably want to look into the request headers for the x-forwarded-for value, as the Azure front end load balancers handle the custom domain stuff and forward it back to the website instance. The Request.URL value will be what the request actually comes in as, Nancy won't be able to change that.

Comment: x-Forwarded-For is an IP:port, doesn't seem like it. There's a host - I can try that one.